# How to find number of different nations in list of Persons?

Tags: python, python-2.x

How to find number of different nations in list of Persons ? I have simple class Person

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, nation, name):
        self.nation = nation
        self.name = name
        ...
```

I can iterate through list and increment dictionary (if exists key nation else put with value 1) and get number of key si number of nations and count of members by nation but I wonder is there any more pythonic way, like linq in c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the number of different nations, you can simply take the `len` of a `set`.  For example:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, nation, name):
        self.nation = nation
        self.name = name

People = [Person("Canada", "Dave"), Person("Scotland", "Alex"), Person("Canada", "Fred"), Person("Japan", "Kenta")]
```

and then

```
>>> set(p.nation for p in People)
set(['Canada', 'Japan', 'Scotland'])
>>> {p.nation for p in People} # python 2.7
set(['Canada', 'Japan', 'Scotland'])
>>> len({p.nation for p in People})
3
```

The `(x for x in y)` is a "generator expression", and the `{x for x in y}` is a "set comprehension" (only available in 2.7+ -- it's like a list comprehension but for sets.)

If you want more specific information, you can use a `Counter` object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(p.nation for p in People)
>>> c
Counter({'Canada': 2, 'Japan': 1, 'Scotland': 1})
>>> len(c)
3
>>> sum(c.values())
4
```

Comment: +1. Not only was I too slow, I was too slow against a much more complete answer..